# Pointing existing source code to remote .git repository

Tags: git, git-remote

User A and User B have the same code. User A creates a repository (`git init`, `git remote add origin <repo-url>`, `git commit`, `git push` in that order). Remote repository gets created and has the changes from User A.

User B already has the same changes locally but wan't to start pointing and getting tracked by the same repository. How does User B achieve that?

I tried a `git init` followed by a `git remote add origin <repo-url>`. `git branch` does not list any branches, not even `master`. What could be going wrong here?

The projects being added are already inside an existing Git repository. i.e My project structure is Xdir/Ydir. Xdir is a Git repo. Everything I'm trying to do now is inside Ydir. That was not a problem for User A. But somehow User B is having issues pointing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch the branches to see them first. Once User B adds the remote branch do a

```
git fetch origin
```

to see the remote branches

Answer (score 0):

It would be much easier for User B to start with `git clone <User A repo-url>`.

But if you really want to start with separate `git init` you should do `git merge` first.

User B should do:

```
git init
git add .
git commit
git remote add origin <User A repo-url>
git fetch
git merge origin/master
```

Now they can exchange their changes.